# Combined PK leads to duplicate column definition

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am new to JPA and Hibernate and I am trying to create an assignment table with an additional column position which is part of the PK which also contains a FK reference.

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ComponentAssignmentEntityPK.class)
public class ComponentAssignmentEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Integer containerID;
    private Integer elementID;
    @Id
    private Integer position;
    ....
    @ManyToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="CONTAINERID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    public ComponentEntity getContainer() {
        return container;
    }
}
```

My Key class looks basically like this

```
public class ComponentAssignmentEntityPK implements Serializable {
    private Integer containerID;
    private Integer position;
    ....
}
```

However, if I now generate the init script using Hibernate it contains a duplicate definition for the containerid

```
create table ComponentAssignment (
    containerID integer not null,
    position integer not null,
    ...
    elementID integer,
    container_id integer not null, <===
    primary key (containerID, position)
);
```

What am I doing wrong? I am using Hibernate 4.3.5.Final.

Answer (score 0):

In your entity, you have defined two columns with same name `CONTAINERID`, one of them should be with different name.

As a result, when table creation script is generated, `container_id` is defined to make different

```
create table ComponentAssignment (
    containerID integer not null,    //refer to PK column name with @Id
    position integer not null,
    ...
    elementID integer,
    container_id integer not null,   //refer to column for ComponentEntity with @ManyToOne
    primary key (containerID, position)
```

);

Assuming that it can be solved by renaming the column name for `ComponentEntity` like this;

```
@ManyToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="container_id", referencedColumnName = "ID")
```

Comment: Well what you are saying is not absolutely true. I want my entity to only have one column containerid ... I dont want the container_id column. I am just assuming to need the @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn definition to define how the ComponentEntity should be resolved via a foreign key ... I am referring to this tutorial http://giannigar.wordpress.com/2009/09/04/mapping-a-many-to-many-join-table-with-extra-column-using-jpa/ ... Sorry but I dont understand how your solution can help.

Comment: You need one column defined for `@ManyToOne` relationship to `ComponentEntity`. If not , you must change your entity model design as necessary.

Comment: @RoK In addition, I am sure that the example in your link will not work correctly.

Comment: reducing PrimaryKeyJoinColumn to JoinColumn did the deal